# How to get value in async function?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I tried two function in(async function,normal function)in node js.normal function its sucessfully return value.but async function its cant return value.How to fix it

**normal function**

index.js

```
var sample_data = require('./product')

const data = sample_data
console.log(data)
```

product.js

```
function sample()
{
    console.log("hai")
    return "hello"
}

module.exports = sample
```

**async function**

index.js

```
var sample_data = require('./product')

const data = sample_data
console.log(data)
```

product.js

```
async function sample()
{
    console.log("hai")
    return "hello"
}

module.exports = sample
```

**normal function**

Expected output
hai
hello

**async function**

Expected ouput
hai
hello

but I got output
[AsyncFunction: sample]

Comment: `async` function returns promise. `sample().then(v => console.log(v))`

Comment: you need to use await in the async function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

Using `then`

```
sample().then(result => console.log(result));
```

OR using `await` to wait and get results till execution of next statement

```
var result = await sample();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

async functions wrap the return value in promise so to see results you need .then()

```
   sample().then(result=>{console.lot(result)});
```

Comment: sample was the name of the function you made, add it where you want to console.log the results of sample()